# How do I transfer Comments from one Facebook App ID to Another?

Tags: facebook, comments, app-id

Is there any way to transfer comments from a "deleted" Facebook app (that is still receiving comments) to a new app id? The app was deleted by accident quite some time ago but we now have thousands of comments that have been entered using it. I'm afraid I will lose all of the comments if I simply switch to a new app. The app id seems to function just fine with the commenting mechanism, but I can't manage it or use it in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no automated way of doing this. However, you can read them programatically from your deleted app (provided you have the permissions) and then post it again on your new app. 
You can get the original app's feed using the following (PHP) code:

```
$response=file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/feed&access_token=".$facebook_access_token);
$response_array=json_decode($response,true);
// $id: ID of the page where the comments are
```

You can also customize this query by adding pagination parameters like since,limit,until etc. Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for documentation.

And can be reposted to your app by HTTP POSTing to the same URL. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts for details.

Please understand that you can't post as the original author - so you can only post the text and perhaps manually add the context of the original author. so i.e:

"Shreeni: 'This is a cool app' "

will have to become

"App: 'Shreeni said: 'This is a cool app' ' "